# Django custom user model: How to manage staff permissions?

Tags: django, django-1.5, django-profiles

I'm trying to benefit from Django 1.5 and created custom user model. In order to use builtin permissions, which I would like to limit access with in the admin interface. I inherited my user class also from PermissionMixin. But when I create new user and check **Staff** box, the new user gets all the access that superuser has.

What am I doing wrong?

## models.py

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('Users must have an email address'))
        user = self.model(email=MyUserManager.normalize_email(email),)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, password=password,)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True,)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'))

    objects = MyUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Comment: Check if default value for is_superuser is set to False. That part of the code is not written here.

Comment: @Sudipta, thanks for the answer, but in PermissionMixin this field is `default=False`, and MyUser inherits from it. Anyway, I can see **is_superuser** field on the user edit page and it is not checked. And there is no other parts of code, except a few methods like getting full name and permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten custom user model. The main difference from the django user model now is that mine does not have **username** field. Here is the code:

```
import warnings
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin,\
    SiteProfileNotAvailable, BaseUserManager
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.http import urlquote
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = CustomUserManager.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
                          is_staff=False, is_active=True, is_superuser=False,
                          last_login=now, date_joined=now, **extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        u = self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
        u.is_staff = True
        u.is_active = True
        u.is_superuser = True
        u.save(using=self._db)
        return u


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(_('middle name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%s/" % urlquote(self.username)

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        "Returns the short name for the user."
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])

    def get_profile(self):
        """
        Returns site-specific profile for this user. Raises
        SiteProfileNotAvailable if this site does not allow profiles.
        """
        warnings.warn("The use of AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE to define user profiles"
                      " has been deprecated.",
            PendingDeprecationWarning)
        if not hasattr(self, '_profile_cache'):
            from django.conf import settings
            if not getattr(settings, 'AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE', False):
                raise SiteProfileNotAvailable(
                    'You need to set AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in your project '
                    'settings')
            try:
                app_label, model_name = settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE.split('.')
            except ValueError:
                raise SiteProfileNotAvailable(
                    'app_label and model_name should be separated by a dot in '
                    'the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE setting')
            try:
                model = models.get_model(app_label, model_name)
                if model is None:
                    raise SiteProfileNotAvailable(
                        'Unable to load the profile model, check '
                        'AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in your project settings')
                self._profile_cache = model._default_manager.using(
                                   self._state.db).get(user__id__exact=self.id)
                self._profile_cache.user = self
            except (ImportError, ImproperlyConfigured):
                raise SiteProfileNotAvailable
        return self._profile_cache
```

Now it works and keeps all default permissions. Also note, that for the admin you must rewrite user **ModelAdmin** and **UserCreationForm** along with **UserChangeForm** classes.

Comment: Using this custom user model, can we create a API in which we will recieve parameter as : "user_is", "old_password","new_password", and using these cam we change password of the user?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem , in my case I had this:

```
class Estudiante(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
name = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=False,blank=False)    
email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='Direccion de correo Electronico',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
    db_index=True,
) 

is_staff = models.BooleanField(u'staff status', default=False,
    help_text=u'Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                'site.')
is_active = models.BooleanField(u'active', default=True,
    help_text=u'Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.')


objects = MyUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

def get_full_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.name

def get_short_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.email

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.email

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    "Does the user have a specific permission?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True
```

and MyUserManager:

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, name,email,  password=None):
    ....
    return user

def create_superuser(self, name,email, password):
    """
    Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
    birth and password.
    """
    user = self.model(
        email=MyUserManager.normalize_email(email),
        name=name,
    )
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_active = True
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

I fixed the problem commented or eliminate the methods "has_perm"  and has_module_perms

```
class Estudiante(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
name = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=False,blank=False)    
email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='Direccion de correo Electronico',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
    db_index=True,
) 

is_staff = models.BooleanField(u'staff status', default=False,
    help_text=u'Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                'site.')
is_active = models.BooleanField(u'active', default=True,
    help_text=u'Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.')


objects = MyUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

def get_full_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.name

def get_short_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.email

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.email
```

Comment: Sorry for a long delay, I really had no occasion to check your suggestion, now I'm back to this problem. You don't need `has_perm` and `has_module_perms` methods, because you inherit them from **PermissionsMixin**. I've totally rewritten my custom user model, you can see in in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Still relevant | 
I had the same problem, only superuser had all permissions.Even if I create staff and assign them permissions, I could log-in using that account but it showed "you dont have permissions to edit or view anything".
But removing "has_perm" and "has_module_perms" from custom user class fixed it.
Thank you